Implementing a Getter method into a Kotlin Proto DataStore variable
So, I've defined a simple data class, as follows:
@Serializable
data class UserSession(
    var name: String = "",
    val isEnrolled: Boolean = false,
)

This class relates to another Kotlin class, UserSessionViewModel, as follows:
class UserSessionViewModel(
    private val application: Application,
    private val store: DataStore<UserSession>,
) : AndroidViewModel(application), KoinComponent {

    /**
     * A [Flow] representing the current [UserSession].
     * It emits every time the user session is updated.
     */
    val userSession: Flow<UserSession>
        get() = store.data

    /**
     * Enrolls the user in the application.
     * Updates the `isEnrolled` property of [UserSession] to true.
     */
    fun enroll() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            store.updateData {
                it.copy(isEnrolled = true)
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Caches the given name in the [UserSession].
     *
     * @param name The name to be cached.
     */
    fun cacheName(name: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            store.updateData {
                it.copy(name = name)
            }
        }
    }

    fun getEnrolledName(): String {
        val enrolledName: String
        viewModelScope.launch {
            store.<proper-method?> {
                //does this work?
                enrolledName = it.let(name)
        }
        return enrolledName
    }

//and other, similar write-only methods into the data-store
}

My question:  how would I implement a simple 'getter' method into one of these variables?  Or, is there a need to do so?
The other examples I've found always talk about implementing a Preferences DataStore...this isn't quite  the case.  I just want to make sure my variable of interest, persists across app restarts, and can be read within my UserSessionViewModel object's methods
Thanks in advance,
Charles.

What do you mean by "implement a simple 'getter' method into one of these variables"? What do you want to get and what variables are you talking about? The code looks fine to me, what is missing, what do you need? (Except, perhaps, making userSession to a StateFlow: val userSession = store.data.stateIn(...) -- But that doesn't seem to be relevant to your question.)

see above.  I added a sample getting function with a missing piece.

No, you do not need additional functions to retrieve parts of your UserSession. Everything needed is already returned by the userSession flow.
That said, you should only expose StateFlows in your view model:
val userSession: StateFlow<UserSession?> = store.data.stateIn(
    scope = viewModelScope,
    started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
    initialValue = null,
)

This way the content of userSession behaves more like a variable: A StateFlow always has a value property. If you are only interested in the current user name you can call this:
viewModel.userSession.value?.name

Usually you just want to regularly collect the flow, though. You can then access the collected value to retrieve the name property.
